# What sort of cable is this?

Tags: cable

I have no idea what this cable is. I have searched high and low looking for the name for about three weeks. Sorry about the pictures; I'm no photographer.

[image]

Before anyone asks: No. I would imagine these don't generally have light switches on them! I needed a switch and that's all I had.

Comment: That's a low-current connector, so the wall switch is used for switching logic, not line voltage.  Could be a switch for something like home automation, e.g. X10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is certainly not a standard computer cable.
Even without the light-switch :-)

Looks like a straight 12-pin cable, could be used for anything.

Occasionally you will see such cables between motherboard and front-panel in OEM systems.
(For audio-jacks, power/reset-switches, LEDS, sometimes USB or Firewire.)

Standard of-the-shelf motherboards have standardized connectors for those, so they match up with the standard connectors on of-the-shelf normal system-cases.
But OEMs sometimes saves a couple of dollars by using non-standard wiring.
(They often use custom cases and custom motherboards they design themselves, so they can do whatever they want.)

You frequently find non-standard wiring in servers as well. There is far less standardization in servers when it comes to form-factor and internal cabling so more or less anything goes on those.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a Molex-to-12-pin adapter then? (12-pin being the sort of 12-pin in my pictures of course.)

Comment: I have never seen one. Why would anyone make a adapter for a 4-pin (molex) to a 12-pin connector ? That makes no sense. If you need one you would have to break out the soldering iron.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it is just a generic 12 pin female Free Hanging, Panel Mount connector.

You will need to perform some mesurements to see exactly which one you need but you can go a parts supplier website like [DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv90=2&FV=fff40016%2Cfff802f5%2C1600004%2C16002a8%2C800000f%2C800006a&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) to buy one.